# Nuxt, Webpack and mysql package: Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence

Tags: javascript, mysql, webpack, nuxt.js

I want to use the [mysql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) with webpack, and I always get the error

> Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence.

I have read these posts:

- ["Uncaught Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence" with devtools off - Electron + MySQL node driver + Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075019/uncaught-error-received-packet-in-the-wrong-sequence-with-devtools-off-elec)
- [Webpack 4: Target: NodeJS. Mode: production; MySQL Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359623/webpack-4-target-nodejs-mode-production-mysql-error-received-packet-in-the)
- [serverless framework, typescript, nodejs and mysql - Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470960/serverless-framework-typescript-nodejs-and-mysql-error-received-packet-in-t)

But in my case nothing helped.
I am using nuxt.js and I have tried the mangle trick `UglifyjsWebpackPlugin` and also tried to switch between modes, but nothing helped.

Is there anyone who has experienced something similar and knows how to solve it?

Cheers

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace and when exactly this error happens

Answer (score 1):

I just found out what was the problem:
I was actually using netlify-lambda (https://www.npmjs.com/package/netlify-lambda) to write a lambda function where I needed the mysql. 
This all resides within a project where I have nuxt and a webpack config.

What I did not realize was that the netlify lambda uses it's own webpack config to build and serve my node function. So I was always adding the config stuff into the wrong webpack config.
Now that I disabled minification at the right place it worked.

Comment: I am in this same predicament. Can you elaborate on what you did to remedy this issue?

Comment: I added a new `webpack-config.functions.js` just for my functions. And then when starting `$ yarn netlify-lambda serve ./netlify-lambda-src --config webpack-config.functions.js` I indicated which webpack config the lambda should run.
Of course that webpack contained the minification stuff:
`module.exports = {
  // mysql and webpack minification don't like each other:
  // https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1548
  optimization: { minimize: false }
}`

Comment: I hope you see what I mean without the linebreaks (there is one important one starting before the word `optimization`...